# Exporting a C++ class from a .SO ( linux )

Tags: c++, linux, class, export, shared-libraries

How can I export whole class to shared library?
Is it posible to use THIS library by other languages? ( pascal )

Answer (score 2):

By default all symbols are visible in a linux shared library.  So everything you would need to use the class from another program is already exported.

Usually c++ classes can't be used directly by other languages, but there are several ways to work around this.   For example you could write a C wrapper or use SWIG.

Answer (score 1):

By default, every function in a shared object is exported.  So unless you are using a linker script to change that default, you should be good to go.

There are some ways to change that default.  For example, specifying the `-Blocal` will reduce any symbols not assigned to a version.  Are you using the flag?